# Android how get device display colors

Tags: android

I want to get display colors suppored for current device
here are example

> google_pixel:16M colors
>   samsung_c3300k_champ:256K colors

**note: above value retrieved from device specification sites for example**

also, I get that value is base on display bit for eg: device supports 24 bit then 2^24=16,777,216

but how to get current display bit that is not known

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity, Why do you need that display colors? What are you going to do with that?

Comment: I am working on custom device and right now it's part of specification list, this device is not listed on any specification sites

Answer (score 0):

[`getPixelFormat()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display#getPixelFormat()) could be used to get the pixel format of the display.
But since API 17, it always returns [`RGBA_8888`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html#RGBA_8888).

**R** - 8 bits

**G** - 8 bits

**B** - 8 bits

This comes out to be 24 bits used to represent a single pixel on the display.

Such a display can show `2^24 = 16,777,216` colors.

Comment: I thinks it will be not useful as this method is no longer supported. The result is always PixelFormat.RGBA_8888.